# Слияние вложенных списков в словаре

Tags: python, code-style, словари

Допустим, есть такая структура данных:

```
data = {
  'items': [
    {'subitems': ['lol', 'wut']},
    {'subitems': ['wut', 'lol']}
  ]
}
```

Для слияния всех списков `subitems`, я пишу такой код:

```
subitems = []
for item in data['items']:
  subitems.extend(item['subitems'])
```

Какие есть способы решить такую задачу еще более элегантно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему ваше решение и так вполне элегантное,
но можете ещё проще сделать:

```
from itertools import chain
chain( *( item['subitems'] for item in data['items'] ) )
```

Comment: У автора список плоский, а указанный chain выдаст список со списками. Можно, конечно, list(chain.from_iterable([item['subitems'] for item in data['items']])), но у автора нагляднее ;)

Comment: @idlesign: ваша правда, пофиксил! спасибо большое

Comment: Симпатично получилось. Добавлю балл.

Comment: @idlesign: Спасибо большое! Мне тоже нравится

Answer (score 0):

Это типовая задача для встроенной функции `reduce`:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y['subitems'], data['items'], [])
```

Comment: Начиная с третьей версии, *reduce* может быть найдена в модуле *functools*, ввиду того, что в подавляющем большинстве случаев проигрывает в читаемости for-конструкциям.

Comment: Не думаю, что третья версия уже в тренде.

Comment: Безотносительно распространённости третьей версии, читаемый код всегда популярен.

Comment: Читаемость - это не функция от длины кода. Выражение алгоритма через `reduce` менее читаемо только для тех, у кого мало опыта в функциональном программировании. Для тех же, у кого есть опыт, такая запись, наоборот, выглядит более читаемо. Тут как с иероглифами: когда ты их знаешь, они удобнее из-за своей компактности.

Comment: Дэк, про длину кода я ничего не говорил, это вы почему-то про компактность иероглифов вспомнили %) На функциональное программирование тоже вроде не жаловался. За сим предлагаю остаться при своих.

Comment: Говорили. Слова о том, что `reduce` уступает в читаемости `for`-конструкциям, имеют именно такой смысл, что чем подробнее и длиннее расписано то, что нужно сделать, тем читаемее выглядит код.